# building 'pycocotools._mask' extension error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx')

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn

when I run the [tf-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn) following its introductions, I get the following error when I run `make` under the path `../tf-faster-rcnn/data/coco/PythonAPI/`:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
error: unknown file type '.pyx' (from 'pycocotools/_mask.pyx')
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have tried this [method](https://github.com/drufat/triangle/issues/12#issuecomment-225918750), but it doesn't work.